# Uncaught ReferenceError: sort is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, function

What I'm trying to achieve is to make `sort` function inside `pagination()` function work. Everything should be fine but somehow I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: sort is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick (index.html:1)` error in my console, and I don't know what's wrong with it. I'm posting all of my javascript because maybe other functions are causing this problem. What `pagination()` function should do is commented in the script.

```js
// jQuery Datepicker
$(".datepicker").datepicker({  defaultDate: null,
  prevText: "<",
  nextText: ">",
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true,
  yearRange: "1930:2017",
  dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy",
     onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
            $(".search").val(dateText);
        }
});

// filtering functionality
  const endpoint = 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/agowj';
  const people = [];
  fetch(endpoint)
    .then(blob => blob.json())
    .then(data => people.push(...data))


  function findMatches(wordToMatch, people) {
    return people.filter(person => {
      //here we need to figure out if the person matches what was searched
      const regex = new RegExp(wordToMatch, 'gi');
      return person.id.toString().match(regex) || person.firstName.match(regex) || person.lastName.match(regex) || person.dateOfBirth.toString().match(regex) || person.function.match(regex) || person.experience.toString().match(regex)
    });
  }

  function displayMatches() {
    const matchArray = findMatches(this.value, people);
    const html = matchArray.map(person => {
      return `
      <tr>
      <td>${person.id}</td>
      <td>${person.firstName}</td>
      <td>${person.lastName}</td>
      <td>${person.dateOfBirth}</td>
      <td>${person.function}</td>
      <td>${person.experience}</td>
      </tr>
      `;
    }).join('');
    suggestions.innerHTML = html;
  }

  // this part fires displayMatches function every time a keyboard button is pressed or the date is selected.
  const searchInput = document.querySelector('.search');
  const suggestions = document.querySelector('.suggestions');

  searchInput.addEventListener('change', displayMatches);
  searchInput.addEventListener('keyup', displayMatches);

  function pagination() {
    // get the table element
    let table = document.getElementById("myTable"),
    // number of rows per page
    n = 5,
    // number of rows of the table
    rowCount = table.rows.length,
    // get the first cell's tag name (in the first row)
    firstRow = table.rows[0].firstElementChild.tagName,
    // boolean var to check if table has a head row
    hasHead = (firstRow === "TH"),
    // an array to hold each row
    tr = [],
    // loop counters, to start count from rows[1] (2nd row) if the first row has a head tag
    i,ii,j = (hasHead)?1:0,
    // holds the first row if it has a (<TH>) & nothing if (<TD>)
    th = (hasHead?table.rows[(0)].outerHTML:"");
    // count the number of pages
    let pageCount = Math.ceil(rowCount / n);
    // if we had one page only, then we have nothing to do ..
    if (pageCount > 1) {
      // assign each row outHTML (tag name & innerHTML) to the array
      for (i = j,ii = 0; i < rowCount; i++, ii++)
      tr[ii] = table.rows[i].outerHTML;
      // create a div block to hold the buttons
      table.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend","<div id='buttons'></div");
      // the first sort, default page is the first one
      sort(1);
    };

    // (p) is the selected page number. it will be generated when a user clicks a button
    function sort(p) {
      /* create (rows) a variable to hold the group of rows
      ** to be displayed on the selected page,
      ** (s) the start point .. the first row in each page, Do The Math
      */
      let rows = th,s = ((n * p)-n);
      for (i = s; i < (s+n) && i < tr.length; i++)
      rows += tr[i];

      // now the table has a processed group of rows ..
      table.innerHTML = rows;
      // create the pagination buttons
      document.getElementById("buttons").innerHTML = pageButtons(pageCount,p);
      // CSS Stuff
      document.getElementById("id"+p).setAttribute("class","active");
    }
    function pageButtons(pCount,cur) {
      /* this variables will disable the "Prev" button on 1st page
      and "next" button on the last one */
      let prevDis = (cur == 1)?"disabled":"",
      nextDis = (cur == pCount)?"disabled":"",
      /* this (buttons) will hold every single button needed
      ** it will creates each button and sets the onclick attribute
      ** to the "sort" function with a special (p) number..
      */
      buttons = "<input type='button' value='&lt;&lt; Prev' onclick='sort("+(cur - 1)+")' "+prevDis+">";
      for (i=1; i<=pCount;i++)
      buttons += "<input type='button' id='id"+i+"'value='"+i+"' onclick='sort("+i+")'>";
      buttons += "<input type='button' value='Next &gt;&gt;' onclick='sort("+(cur + 1)+")' "+nextDis+">";
      return buttons;
    }
  }

$(document).ready(function() {
    console.info("Ready!");
    setTimeout(() => {
        displayMatches();
        pagination();
    }, 350);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>random Title</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="content-input-container">
      <input type="text" class="search" name="something" placeholder="Search">
      <div class="datepicker"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="content-table-container">
      <table id="myTable">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>first name</th>
            <th>last name</th>
            <th>date of birth</th>
            <th>function</th>
            <th>experience</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="suggestions">
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: I'm guessing your script is wrapped inside of a `load` event handler, so there is no global `sort` function. The only `sort` function you've written is inside of another function that runs a `load` time. You can do `window.sort = sort` or you can change your script so it's not inside of a `load` event function.

Comment: Could you please tell me something more about window.sort = sort and where should I write this?